# Fail when duplicate key

Tags: ansible

How can I configure Ansible to assert duplicate keys?

I don't want to rely on `ANSIBLE_DUPLICATE_YAML_DICT_KEY` , I'd like to assert this with a task.

Imagine this dict, which contains duplicate keys:

```yaml
my_dict:
  one:
  one:
```

I've tried:

```yaml
- assert:
    that:
      - my_dict | unique == my_dict
```

But this fails even when there are no duplicate keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Duplicate keys are discarded during parsing, so there is no way to detect that they were present once parsing is finished. Setting [`DUPLICATE_YAML_DICT_KEY`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#duplicate-yaml-dict-key) to `error` is the only way to turn this into a failure.

Comment: How can I read that value when executing a playbook? I've tried debugging it, but the var is undefined.

Comment: The configuration value? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/config_lookup.html